# Maven webapp archetype doesn't create java folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications, build

I initialize the project with the following command

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=tuomas -DartifactId=test -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false`

which should create standard java webapp project structure, including `src/main/java` folder. Instead, it only creates `src/main/webapp` and `src/main/resources`, but not `src/main/java`. When I add new java class in eclipse wizard, it ends up under `src/main/resources`.

What is wrong with the maven command, and how to fix this?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it wasn't supposed to create it https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/. Just create it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As said correctly by Tunaki, you need to create those folders yourself.
The typical steps you need to follow are :

- ***mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=tuomas -DartifactId=test -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false***  which creates a new standard webapp project.
- To convert a Maven based Java project to support IDE, you use this command :
  ***mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0***
- Import this project into Eclipse as existing maven project
- Create new folder named java under *src/main* directory. You may open the Navigator perspective which shows all folders in your project
- Switch back to the Project explorer perspective and update maven project
  you will see the *src/main/java* as source folder. Now you can add a java class to this folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` shouldn't be used; that plugin is deprecated and no longer maintained. M2E should be used instead.